# Confusion about "as"

Tags: sentence-construction

When I first wrote

> I am Taiwanese not Chinese as most of people in Taiwan considered themselves to be today.

I mean that

1. I am Taiwanese not Chinese.
2. Most people in Taiwan considered the same as me that they are Taiwanese not Chinese.

But when I think it again, will it make a confusion?

Can it somehow be misinterpreted as

> I am Taiwanese not (Chinese as most of people in Taiwan considered themselves to be today).

which somehow is completely opposite in meaning. (Meaning people in Taiwan considered themselves to be Chinese today, which is wrong.)

Comment: A minor correction: it should be "as they **consider** themselves to be today."  If it's happening today, it should be in the present tense,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is ambiguous. Some possibilities for rewriting it:

> Like most people in Taiwan today, I consider myself Taiwanese, not Chinese.
>   Most of us in Taiwan today consider ourselves Taiwanese, not Chinese.
>   I am Taiwanese, not Chinese; and most people in Taiwan feel as I do.

Comment: To be pedantic, the third sentence doesn't need the "and" after the semi-colon, and some would call that wrong. My daughter regularly ridicules me for beginning sentences with conjunctions; I think this falls in the same category. :-)

Comment: @Jay Tell your daughter she's old enough to learn her English from books instead of teachers. That prohibition is a whole-cloth invention of 19th-century schoolmasters and has never been observed by Real Writers.

Comment: Yeah, but there's no point to using a semicolon **and** a conjunction, is there?

Comment: @stangdon *O reason not the need: the basest beggar is in the poorest thing superfluous.* I write for the ear, and there's a big difference between  a semicolon and a comma there.

Comment: Oh, dash it all! _I am Taiwanese, not Chinese – and most people in Taiwan feel as I do._

Comment: Per [my comment below](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75896/confusion-about-as#comment146243_75922), I think there's no ambiguity in speech, and I have no slavish respect for the idea that ***not Chinese*** as a "parenthetical" element must always be enclosed in "matching commas". Just use one judiciously-placed comma rather than two.

Answer (score 5):

@StoneyB gives better alternative wordings of this idea.

Let me add:

The sentence as written is not quite grammatically valid. There should not be an "of" before "people" and you shift tense from present "I am" to past "considered". So a grammatically correct sentence would be, "I am Taiwanese not Chinese, as most people in Taiwan consider themselves today."

That said, the sentence is still awkward, and StoneyB's versions are more clear. However, one could say that StoneyB's versions are also weaker. His first two examples shift from "I am Taiwanese" to "I consider myself Taiwanese". Someone might well say, "I do not 'consider myself to be' -- I AM!"

I think his third example is closest in tone to what you are trying to say.

Comment: I agree with your critique. The semicolon is sorta there to cover that awkward segue from "I **am**" to "they **consider**" and keep the energy rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Your question of **ethnicity** is the same faced by people in Singapore, Malaysia, Vietnam, and Cambodia.

China has had a huge population, and by extension, has had a huge **diaspora**.  The distinguishing factor is whether a person is **ethnic** Chinese, that is, originally from China (arguments of ancient population migrations are set aside).  I think ninety percent of the people in Singapore are **ethnic** Chinese. You could refer to yourself as:

> I am **ethnic** Taiwanese.

to make the distinction, though most of the world may still consider you to be **Chinese** since **Taiwan** has also been called **China** in the recent past, and the two countries have been so closely linked throughout history.

In fact, although the world considers the great population of China to be of a **singular Chinese** origin (since they all look very similar in Western eyes), there are **many ethnic groups** which make up the greater **Chinese** population, the largest being **Han**.

I think part of your concern is the proximity of **China** and **how most people in Taiwan consider themselves**.  If you change your sentence phrasing to :

> I am not Chinese, but Taiwanese as most people in Taiwan consider themselves to be these days.

it might be clearer for yourself as well as others.

Comment: I'd be inclined to move the comma in the second example: "I am not Chinese but Taiwanese, as most...".

Answer (score -1):

To me the only ambiguity is because of punctuation. Adding the commas makes your meaning clear. (And as already noted you should change "considered" to present tens and add "the".)

> I am Taiwanese, not Chinese, as most of the people in Taiwan consider
>   themselves to be today.

Unless there is a different technical terms that better applies here, this construction looks like it can be viewed as an *appositive* *or appositive adjective*. (Perhaps we would have to debate whether "Taiwanese" and "Chinese" are nouns or adjectives.) As it is non-restrictive it is generally set off by commas.

http://grammar.about.com/od/basicsentencegrammar/a/buildappositive.htm

As a test you can remove it from the sentence and see that it is still valid even if a little obvious or tautological.

> I am Taiwanese as most of the people in Taiwan consider themselves to be today.

Comment: I have to say that including *both* commas seems to me just as ambiguous as having neither. If you put one comma after *Taiwanese*, that unambiguously implies you're out of step with your countrymen, who mostly consider themselves Chinese. If you put the comma after *Chinese* instead, you're unambiguously asserting that your fellow countrymen mostly feel the same as you (that they're Taiwanese, not Chinese). Try speaking the two different versions, deliberately forcing each of the two different interpretations - the comma marks the ***longest*** pause.

Comment: The long pause sounds more like an em dash to me. But it's not generally accepted to equate commas with pauses in spoken English either way.

Comment: Speak for yourself. So far as I'm concerned one of our most authoritative users here on ELU is John Lawler, and he regularly makes the point that real language is a spoken phenomenon, that commas represent pauses, and that punctuation generally is just part of a clunky attempt to replicate language typographically. And there's absolutely no doubt that the use of commas has declined over many decades - even though it's now common to replace full stops and other "more extreme" delineators with commas.

Comment: You notice that the first two words of my answer are "to me". I also used the word "generally" as you did as well. As it happens I have read a great deal of John Lawler's blog: I have great respect for his writing and because of very knowledgeable people like him I usually hesitate to stick my neck out to answer on the English forum. As for ELL I just thought that OP's attempt was close and didn't need a total re-write. I hardly gave any indication that I'm pedantic about commas and I don't quite understand the offense and the downvote.

Comment: I'm not "offended", and I apologise unreservedly if I've offended you with my comments. I actually have no idea whether most Taiwanese consider themselves to be Taiwanese or Chinese (and in the present context I don't really *want* to know), so OP's example remains "ambiguous" to me. Bear in mind it's entirely a matter of opinion/pragmatic context whether one labels *not Chinese* as an "appositive" element (you could just as well say *as most of the people in Taiwan consider themselves to be today* is appositive). But commas *do* normally represent pauses, of that I'm quite convinced.